# How can I get an Ultron UN-1 wireless numeric keypad to work with Psychopy?

Tags: psychopy

I am keying in a 5 digit number on an Ultron UN-1 wireless numeric keypad. Only some of the numbers are coming through e.g. for 45465 I might get the input below

'numlocknum_4numlockleftnumlocknum_5numlocknumlocknumlockleftnumlocknum_6numlockrightnumlocknumlockreturn'

I am on PsychoPy v1.82.01. I am using an Asus TP300L with Windows 8.1, 64b. The code is below. Thanks for any help.

```
if returnPressed == False:
     while loopTest == True:
         response = event.waitKeys(keyList = None)
         userInput = userInput + response[0]
         print ('response ', response)
         if response[0] == 'return' or response[0] =='escape':
             loopTest = False
             returnPressed = True
```

JR, @jrgray, thanks for the help. I tried your suggestions. It still seems to miss digits. Below are the results I get when I key in the digits 54645 and 45465. It's not just cutting out the last digits.

('user input ', 'num_5num_4num_6return')
('user input ', 'num_4num_5num_6return')

```
while loopTest == True:
    response = event.getKeys(keyList=['num_0', 'num_1', 'num_2', 'num_3', 'num_4', 'num_5', 'num_6', 'num_7', 'num_8', 'num_9', 'return', 'backspace', 'escape'])
    if len(response) > 0:
        userInput = userInput + response[0]
        if response[0] == 'return' or response[0] =='escape':
            loopTest = False
            returnPressed = True

print ('user input ', userInput)
```

Comment: event.waitKeys() returns a list of keys. Generally there is just one, and it makes sense to access just the zeroth element, as you are doing above. But multiple responses can be returned, and if so, you won't be able to access them. Worth checking len(response) here.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the reply. I am only getting one key back from waitKeys during each iteration of the loop. These responses are concatenated into the userInput field which is what I showed as the 'input' above. The keyboard seems to be generating a lot of extra characters and missing some of the digits I actually key in. It's as if they are being lost somewhere along the way. The wireless numeric keyboard works fine with Microsoft Excel as an input device. Any further suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess as what is going on for you.

It looks like that the keypad sends two codes for every keypress: `numlock` followed by `num_x`. So as your code is written, `event.waitKeys()` will need to be called twice to pick them both up. But if your while loop is slow (e.g., because the `print` statement in there), the `num_x` code might sometimes be delivered before `event.waitKeys()` is called the second time. I think `event.waitKeys()` will implicitly call `clearEvents()`, throwing away any keys that have piled up in the meantime (i.e., your `num_x` code).

Things to try:

- remove the print statement to speed up the loop
- use `event.getKeys()` instead of `waitKeys()` (see online API)
- tell `event.getKeys()` to ignore the `numlock` codes, and only pay attention to the numbers you care about: `keyList=['num_1', 'num_2', 'num_3']` (see API)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to eliminate the wireless element from the problem by connecting a standard keyboard with a USB cable to another USB port on my laptop. All the digits keyed on the numeric pad worked correctly. I retested the wireless and lo and behold it started to work perfectly. I assume that something in Windows plug and play algorithm reconfigured a driver when the standard keyboard was plugged in. Thanks all for the help.